# image_resize() with blank space

Tags: images

Any way to resize an image without crop and add new blank space?

Using image_resize() from wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all pay attention that `image_resize()` function is deprecated! Use `wp_get_image_editor()` instead of it. This function will return an instance of `WP_Image_Editor` class (or WP_Error if some issues appear during loading your image). This class has `resize` method which accepts three arguments: desired width, desired height and crop flag.

Sample usage:

```
$editor = wp_get_image_editor( '/path/to/file.png' );
if ( !is_wp_error( $editor ) ) {
    $editor->resize( $desired_width, $desired_height, true ); // true - do crop, false - don't crop
}
```

Back to your question. Unfortunately there is no way to do what you want to do. Your image aspect ratio doesn't equal to desired aspect ratio, that is why whitespace appears. If you crop the image, you will loose parts of your image from top and bottom, but in this case you won't see whitespaces...

Comment: And this will add blank space as i want?

Comment: So should i use your code with crop = false, and use some css to create the effect i want?

Comment: it's up to you. Try both approaches and select one which suits the best to you.